# What is the use of -1 in Python for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```py
for passnum in range(len(nlist)-1,0,**-1**):
    ...
```

I found this code line from a website. All I want to know is, What is the use of `-1` at the and of this for loop?

Comment: Have you tried changing it and observe how the behavior of the loop changes?

Comment: From the documentation of [range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges), the syntax is `range(start, stop[, step])`. The third parameter is optional is tells the step size.

Comment: The third argument to `range` is the step. Here, the step is `-1`. See [the documentation for the builtin `range` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).
Your `for`-loop will run for all values of `passnum` satisfying `passnum <= len(nlist)-1` and `passnum > 0`.

Comment: range is a built in Python function and the official documentation is very good. It pays off regularly visiting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will decrement the value by 1 for each iteration

This value is called as `step` which tells the `for loop` to how to get the next value for the iteration. It can be both negative and positive, but not zero.

the positive step means it will increase the iteration value from the first argument to the second argument

example if step is 2 then 0,2,4,6,8,10

```
for i in range(0,10,2):
print(i) #0,2,4,8
```

The negative step means it will decrease the iteration value from the first argument to the second argument

For example if it is -2 then
10,8,6,4,2

```
for i in range(10,0,-2):
 print(i) #10,8,6,4,2
```